# Sequelize how to select all Tours that belongs to a Category?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have four tables, a category has many region, a region has many location, a location has many tour, like a stair,  I want to select all tours that belong to one category, I tried this solution but it always return all the tour, seems like the "where" is placed in the wrong place because it checks for the condition of Region, not the Tour, and return all the tour.

```
 Tour.findAndCountAll({
        include: {
            model: Location,
            include: {
                model: Region,
                include: {
                    model: Category,
                    where: {
                        id: req.params.category
                    }
                }
            }
        },
```

Thanks in advance :"D

I tried to directly include Category in Tour but Sequelize doesn't support that

Comment: Please show the generated SQL for both COUNT and SELECT SQL queries